# How to use a variable inside function in R

Tags: r

I'd like to use a variable in my function but I can't figure out how to do this. Here is my function and the call on a data.frame:

```
errorByAleles <- function(values){
  counts1 <- as.data.frame(table(values), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  modal_value1 <- which.max(counts1$Freq)
  div <- nrow(values)
  return ((sum(counts1$Freq)-counts1$Freq[modal_value1])/div)
}

error1 <- apply(X=ind1[,2:9],MARGIN=2,FUN=errorByAleles)
```

Dimmension of data.frame on which I apply my function :

```
> dim(ind1)  
[1] 9 9
```

The problem is with div <- nrow(values). div = 9 is what I need here. So how to get nrow for my "values" inside function ? Am I clear ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: You can't do that with the function as written because `div` is only defined within the scope of your function.  You'll need to either change the function or calculate the value of `div` separately outside of the function.

Comment: Mmmmm, I guess I'll have to change my function, as div is variable...

Comment: `MARGIN=2` requires an array of at least two dimensions, but `ind1[2:9]` is a vector, maybe you meant to do `ind1[2:9, ]` or `ind1[, 2:9]` ?

Comment: Question - since `ind1` has `dim` 9x9, why does `ind1[2:9]` not throw an error when you call `apply`? That shouldn't work, are you missing a comma somewhere, like `ind1[2:9,]` or `ind1[,2:9]`?

Comment: @flodel Yes, thanks for pointing this out, I meant [,2:9]. Doesn't solve my problem though...

Comment: @mathematical.coffee. You are right, but apply didn't throw any error even if I missed a coma.... Code corrected.

Comment: Have you tried `ind[,2:9]` and `length(values)` together? It works for me. I have even inserted a `print(dim)` in the body of the function and it returns a bunch of `9`s as expected.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, It worked ! Thanks a bunch ! Learned a lot today ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `apply()`, you are running your function on every column of your data. When the function is called by `apply()`, it is passed a vector representing a column. So instead of `nrow(values)`, you should use `length(values)`.

Comment: That's what I tried first, but length(values) gives me 1 inside the function.....